# Having trouble updating an array of objects which is passed from child to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array

```
let Data = [
{name: 'item-1', quantity: 0},
{name: 'item-2', quantity: 0},
{name: 'item-3', quantity: 0},
{name: 'item-4', quantity: 0},
{name: 'item-5', quantity: 0},
{name: 'item-6', quantity: 0},
]
```

which I am passing to a child component that updates the array based on some conditional logic and passes that data back to the parent component.

```
const Parent () => {

    
    let Data = [
        {name: 'item-1', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'item-2', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'item-3', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'item-4', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'item-5', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'item-6', quantity: 0},

]

    const getData = function(data){
        data.foreach((element) => {
            let currentElement = Data.find(x => x.name === element.name);
            currentElement.quantity += element.quantity;

        })
        return Data

    }

    return (
        <>
            <Child getData={getData}

        </>
)



}
```

what I would like to happen is when this data is updated in the child component I want to update the original data array which is at the top of the Parent component. I am able to do just this but when I navigate away from the parent component and then navigate back to the parent it reinitializes the array to the original values instead of saving the updated data

does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I feel like I am so close and on the right track here I just need that last push

Comment: You'll want to make ``Data`` a state variable using ``useState`` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Here's an example of passing state variables to child components https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/passing-state-of-parent-to-child-component-as-props.

Comment: If the parent data gets reinitilized, then you might want to try to move the state up a level

Answer (score 0):

```
// You could move 'Data' outside your component and make it const
const initialData = [
    {name: 'item-1', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'item-2', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'item-3', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'item-4', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'item-5', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'item-6', quantity: 0},
];

const Parent = () => {
    // You should probably add useState with initial data like this:
    const [dataArray, setDataArray] = React.useState(initialData)

    // You also wrap your change function with useCallback like this:
    const changeHandler = React.useCallback((newArray) => {
        // Spread operator in order to guarantee mutation and get component updating properly
        setDataArray([...newArrray]);
    }, [dataArray])

    return (
        <>
            <Child dataArray={dataArray} changeDataArray={changeHandler} />
        </>
    )
}

// Then on Child component you change 'quantity' property like this:

const Child = ({ dataArray, changeHandler }) => {

    // ...

    const changeArrayValues = function(){       
        const newArray = [...dataArray];
        // As we know newArray[0] is there I just changed its quantity for example purpose
        newArray[0].quantity = 10;
        // Call `changeHandler` with the new array and `dataArray` gets updated
        changeHandler(newArray)
    }

    // ...

}
```